# How to have same attribute instance applied to multiple variable instances in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, attributes, unity-editor, unity3d-editor

I am a Unity Developer and I am trying to create an attribute called "ArrangeAttribut" that will Draw multiple variables in a single row.

Simply put, when I create the following class:

```
public class Testing: MonoBehaviour
{
    [Arrange] public bool bool1, bool2;
    public int anotherVariable;
}
```

I want the inspector to show:

[image: The inspector should show this]

For that, I will have to have the Same Attribute Instance applied to Multiple Variable Instances. Does C# allow this, and if yes, how to achieve it. Also, if there are other ways to arrange multiple variables in one row (**Using an Attribute**), please suggest them.

Code for ArrangeAttribute:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
# if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
# endif


[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ArrangeAttribute : PropertyAttribute {  }

# if UNITY_EDITOR
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(ArrangeAttribute))]
public class ArrangeAttributeDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        EditorGUI.PropertyField(position, property, new GUIContent(property.name));
    }
}
# endif
```

Thanks.

Comment: In general please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Also this question has nothing to do with `unity-ecs` or `unit-testing` ... please read the tag descriptions

Comment: And then StackOverflow is not for asking "Please someone (tell me how to) implement XY!" but rather for asking like "I have the following specific situation where I try to implement XY but instead ZZ happens - what am I doing wrong?" - Please make sure to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then after you researched and have a specific implementation issue come here with a specific question :)

Comment: You should probably start at [Property Drawers -> bottom section is about Attribute and decorator drawers](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PropertyDrawer.html)